# How does user_url work and how do I find out how pre-defined RoR functions work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#code-first_create_action

I'm looking at the above after Listing 7.28.

1. Where is the user_url function here coming from: redirect_to user_url(@user)
2. Is "user_url(@user)" == "user_path(user)"?
3. How can I find what functions like user_url are referring to? When I import it in RubyMine, it's unable to find the documentation or method signature...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those urls are provided by Rails' [UrlHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html), and are defined in your config/routes.rb file.

1. user_url is defined in the file `config/routes.rb`. Check out [Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).
2. user_url and user_path are essentially the same. `user_url(@user)` will include the full URL including the host (http://www.example.com/users/1), while `user_path(@user)` will only output the path (/users/1)
3. You can go to http://localhost:3000/routes in your browser (assuming your Rails server is running on port 3000), or in your terminal type `rails routes`.